# усовершенствовать js код

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

При скроллинге страницы с хедером должны происходить некоторые изменения типа уменьшение ширины, появления `margin-top`, `transform: rotate`, решил через `classList.add` писать, ибо через `style.property` еще ужаснее выглядит.
Посоветуйте что-нибудь дабы код нормально выглядел:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset,
    header = document.querySelector('header'),
    topHeader = document.querySelector('.topHeader'),
    subHeader = document.querySelector('.subHeader');

  if (scrolled > 1000) {
    header.classList.add('minWidth');
    header.style.top = scrolled + 'px';
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('minWidth');
    header.style.top = '0';
  }

  if (scrolled > 2000) {
    topHeader.classList.add('mTop');
  } else {
    topHeader.classList.remove('mTop');
  }

  if (scrolled > 3000) {
    topHeader.classList.add('maxHeight');
  } else {
    topHeader.classList.remove('maxHeight');
  }

  if (scrolled > 4000) {
    subHeader.classList.add('dblock');
  } else {
    subHeader.classList.remove('dblock');
  }
}
```

Comment: одинаковый код можно в функцию вынести

Comment: я понимаю, но не могу ее придумать

Comment: как минимум 3 последних if у тебя полностью одинаковые. переносишь этот код в функцию, и параметрами передаешь смещение, элемент и класс

Comment: Крайне рекомендуется дебаунсить обработчик onscroll потому что он происходит дохрена раз

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, и так сойдет :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
 let Y = this.pageYOffset+this.innerHeight,
  h = document.querySelector('header'),
  tH = document.querySelector('.topHeader'),
  sH = document.querySelector('.subHeader');
 [[1000,h,"minWidth"],[2000,tH,"mTop"],[3000,tH,"maxHeight"],[4000,sH,"dblock"]]
 .filter((a)=>a[1].classList[Y > a[0] ? "add" : "remove"](a[2]));
});
```

```css
html { height: 4100px }

body *::before { position: fixed; content: attr(class) }

.topHeader::before { margin-top: 20px }

.subHeader::before { margin-top: 40px }
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="topHeader"></div>
<div class="subHeader"></div>
```

Comment: мне нравится, спасибо)

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onscroll = function () {

  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset,
    header = qS('header'),
    topHeader = qS('.topHeader'),
    subHeader = qS('.subHeader'),
    a = scrolled > 1000,
    b = scrolled > 2000,
    c = scrolled > 3000,
    d = scrolled > 4000;

  if (!!a) {
    header.classList.add('minWidth');
    header.style.top = scrolled + 'px';
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('minWidth');
    header.style.top = '0';
  }


  function qS(el) {
    return document.querySelector(el);
  }


  function checkPos(condition, elem, className) {
    if (!!condition) {
      return elem.classList.add(className)
    } else {
      return elem.classList.remove(className)
    }
  }

  checkPos(b, topHeader, 'mTop');
  checkPos(c, topHeader, 'maxHeight');
  checkPos(d, subHeader, 'dblock');
}
```

Comment: что еще можно тут сделать??

Comment: `!!` не нужен - выражения и так bool

Answer (score -2):

А может как то так?
На работоспособность не проверял :(

```
window.onscroll = function () {
var scrolled = window.pageYOffset,
header = document.querySelector('header'),
topHeader = document.querySelector('.topHeader'),
subHeader = document.querySelector('.subHeader');

function move(headerType, addOrRemove, styleClass){
    headerType.classList.addOrRemove(styleClass);
}

switch(scrolled){
  case scrolled > 1000: move(header, add, minWidth);
                        header.style.top = scrolled + 'px';
                        break;
  case scrolled > 2000: move(topHeader, add, mTop);
                        break;
  case scrolled > 3000: move(topHeader, add, maxHeight);
                        break;
  case scrolled > 4000: move(topHeader, add, dblock);
                        break;  
  default: move(header, remove, minWidth);
           header.style.top = '0';
           move(header, remove, mTop);
           move(header, remove, maxHeight);
           move(header, remove, dblock);
           break;                                                              
}
}
```

Comment: тож думал о свич-кейсе, щас проверим, спасибо)

Comment: Выражение после `case` приводится к логическому `true`/`false` а уже потом проводится сравнение с `scrolled`. Иными словами: `switch` / `case` так не работает!

Comment: написал switch(true) case scrolled>1000, может сработает, так функция move ругается на add и remove